# How to define an abstract collection data type?

Tags: isabelle

There are 4 kinds of collections in my theory. For each collection type I defined `count` and `for_all` operations:

```
theory MyCollections
  imports Main
    "~~/src/HOL/Library/Dlist"
    "~~/src/HOL/Library/Multiset"
begin

typedef 'a mybag = "UNIV :: 'a multiset set" .. (* not unique, not ordered *)
typedef 'a myseq = "UNIV :: 'a list set" ..     (* not unique, ordered *)
typedef 'a myset = "UNIV :: 'a set set" ..      (* unique, not ordered *)
typedef 'a myord = "UNIV :: 'a dlist set" ..    (* unique, ordered *)

setup_lifting type_definition_mybag
setup_lifting type_definition_myseq
setup_lifting type_definition_myset
setup_lifting type_definition_myord

lift_definition mybag_count :: "'a mybag ⇒ 'a ⇒ nat" is "Multiset.count" .
lift_definition myseq_count :: "'a myseq ⇒ 'a ⇒ nat" is "count_list" .
lift_definition myset_count :: "'a myset ⇒ 'a ⇒ nat" is "(λxs x. if x ∈ xs then 1 else 0)" .
lift_definition myord_count :: "'a myord ⇒ 'a ⇒ nat" is "(λxs x. if Dlist.member xs x then 1 else 0)" .

lift_definition mybag_for_all :: "'a mybag ⇒ ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" is "Multiset.Ball" .
lift_definition myseq_for_all :: "'a myseq ⇒ ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" is "(λxs f. list_all f xs)" .
lift_definition myset_for_all :: "'a myset ⇒ ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" is "Ball" .
lift_definition myord_for_all :: "'a myord ⇒ ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool" is "(λxs f. list_all f (list_of_dlist xs))" .
```

I need to define polymorphic operations (`includes` and `includes_all`) for these collection types:

```
lift_definition mybag_includes :: "'a mybag ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" is
  "(λxs x. mybag_count xs x > 0)" .

lift_definition myseq_includes :: "'a myseq ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" is
  "(λxs x. myseq_count xs x > 0)" .

lift_definition myset_includes :: "'a myset ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" is
  "(λxs x. myset_count xs x > 0)" .

lift_definition myord_includes :: "'a myord ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" is
  "(λxs x. myord_count xs x > 0)" .


lift_definition mybag_mybag_includes_all :: "'a mybag ⇒ 'a mybag ⇒ bool" is
  "(λxs ys. mybag_for_all ys (mybag_includes xs))" .

lift_definition mybag_myseq_includes_all :: "'a mybag ⇒ 'a myseq ⇒ bool" is
  "(λxs ys. myseq_for_all ys (mybag_includes xs))" .

(* ... and 14 more similar operations for other type combinations *)
```

Some test cases:

```
value "mybag_myseq_includes_all (Abs_mybag {#1::nat,2,4,5,3,4#}) (Abs_myseq [1::nat,2])"
value "mybag_myseq_includes_all (Abs_mybag {#1::nat,2,4,5,3,4#}) (Abs_myseq [1::nat,7])"
```

The problem is that these operations are structurally identical and I don't want to duplicate them. I try to define an abstract collection type:

```
typedecl 'a mycol
consts
  mycol_count :: "'a mycol ⇒ 'a ⇒ nat"
  mycol_for_all :: "'a mycol ⇒ ('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool"

definition mycol_includes :: "'a mycol ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" where
  "mycol_includes xs x ≡ mycol_count xs x > 0"

definition mycol_includes_all :: "'a mycol ⇒ 'a mycol ⇒ bool" where
  "mycol_includes_all xs ys ≡ mycol_for_all xs (mycol_includes ys)"
```

But I have no idea how to derive concrete collection types from the abstract one:

```
typedef 'a mybag = "{xs :: 'a mycol. ???}" ..
typedef 'a myseq = "{xs :: 'a mycol. ???}" ..
typedef 'a myset = "{xs :: 'a mycol. ???}" ..
typedef 'a myord = "{xs :: 'a mycol. ???}" ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have axiomatized the abstract collections type, you cannot refine it inside the logic any more. So the proposed approach does not work. But if you leave the container type abstract (as a type variable), then this is possible. I recommend to do that using locales:

```
locale container =
  fixes count :: "'container => 'a => nat"
  and for_all :: "'container => ('a => bool) => bool"
begin

definition "includes" where "includes C x <--> count C x > 0"
definition includes_all where "includes_all C C' <--> for_all C (includes C')"

end
```

Then, you can define your different collection types as usual and obtain the common operations by locale interpretation. For example,

```
interpretation mybag: container mybag_count mybag_forall .
```

generates the abbreviations mybag.includes and mybag.includes_all. Additionally, all theorems that are proven in the locale `container` are also specialized to `mybag` and prefixed with `mybag`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Could you clarify please. Is it possible to automatically generate code equations for `mybag.includes`, etc.? And is it possible to make `includes_all` polymorphic in both arguments? This locale defines `includes_all :: "'a mybag ⇒ 'a mybag ⇒ bool"` but doesn't define `includes_all :: "'a mybag ⇒ 'a myseq ⇒ bool"`

Comment: Oh, I've got how to generate code. I must use global interpretation: `global_interpretation mybag: container mybag_count mybag_for_all
  defines mybag_includes = "mybag.includes" .`

Comment: And also I've got how to define `includes_all` for different collection types. I must use locale expressions: `locale container_pair = container1: container count1 for_all1 + container2: container count2 for_all2`. So the definition of `includes_all` will be as follows: `includes_all C C' ⟷ for_all2 C' (container1.includes C)`

Comment: @Denis: That's right. If you want to combine two different bad implementations in one operations, you need two copies of the locale `container`. Accordingly, you need `n^2` interpretations if you have `n` different containers. `global_interpretation` with `defines` is also the right choice for code generation.